# how to create a listener which can listen for each and every method call, not only test method

Tags: java, testng

I want to write listener in java which can listen to each and every method. Before the method call i want to check if the method is annotated with specific class and will change the logic at run time.

Can someone guide me in this regard ?

I tried **IInvokedMethodListener** of testng but it only works for testng methods i.e annotated with testng annotation e.g beforemethod, aftermethod and test.

Comment: What technologies are you using? And why would you want to do that? Could you explain a little bit more why are you trying to do that? If it's a web framework, you could use an interceptor but seems that your problem could be solved in a simpler way ( Strategy pattern, for instance).

Comment: juliccr thank you for your reply.
I am using java and testng. I want to use it for web test automation framework. In my code Every method is annotated with @Step annotation and i want to set a global flag for that annotation i.e if the method is annotated with `@Step` and flag is set true then @Step will work if the flag is set false then @Step annotation should not have any impact.